# How to import CGAL 2D general polygon from file?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

According to [this](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/classCGAL_1_1General__polygon__2.html#aa65e28dd16fb0a85402e6bb0d2aa26d6) documentation page the `General_polygon_2` can be imported from a text file using `operator>>`. However the program below can't be compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Gps_circle_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/General_polygon_2.h>

using Kernel = CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>;
using PolygonTraits = CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2<Kernel>;
using Polygon = CGAL::General_polygon_2<PolygonTraits>;

int main()
{
  Polygon pgn;
  std::ifstream fs("abc");
  fs >> pgn;                       // <== error is here
  std::cout << pgn << std::endl;
}
```

(The error output is too long to show it here)

What am I doing wrong?

- CGAL: 5.4.2
- Compiler: GCC 10.3.0
- OS: Xubuntu 20.04.4

**UPDATE**. The same problem with CGAL 5.5 - there are no `operator>>` for the `X_monotone_curve_2` type.

Comment: Is there some particular reason that you've chosen to use an fstream instead of an istream? The page you've linked to uses an istream, yet you've used an fstream. Without any of the compiler error messages, we've got virtually nothing to go on.

Comment: @enhzflep - it shouldn't matter, the ifstream inherits from the istream. Also anybody with the CGAL installed can see these errors after compilation.

Comment: shouldn't (by estimation) or doesn't (through observation) ? :laughs: I've given the same answer on numerous occasions when something wasn't working that I thought should. Did this work before you upgraded from 5.3.x? I note that the latest stable release is just 22 days ago.. Seems likely that you're simply doing it wrong, hence the initial question. (which you didn't answer)

Comment: @enhzflep - did you try to reproduce the error? Maybe I'm doing it wrong, this lib is a very complex bunch of C++ templates... Any good advice would be appreciated

Comment: I did. But gave up when I saw that the library relied upon Boost. Without knowing that the code had been tried as per the documentation, I didn't (don't) really feel like installing all that stuff just to find it was an amateur-hour mistake.
If however, on the other hand, their own examples didn't work, I'd have been far more inclined to dig a little deeper. Templates are indeed complex buggers, with compilation messages that often (usually?) suck. That's why I asked about the code instead of the error-messages. 22 days for a stable release indicates a simple program should work.

Comment: (cont) and when such a obvious difference between their documentation and your code was observed, it seems reasonable to show this difference not to be the thing that breaks it. I dislike streams. Stuff that's simple in x86/x64 assembly suddenly seems to get nasty when templates and streams get involved. I don't have the time or patience for that rubbish. If I'm coding, I expect it do do what I want, without having to rely on someone else's assurance that the magic works.
I.e if I feel in the mood for some fun, I pull out my bootloader and work on a protected-mode mouse driver, in assembly

Comment: It turns out that importing an x-monotone curve of type `Arr_circle_segment_traits_2<>::X_monotone_curve_2` from an input stream is not supported (while exporting to an output stream is supported; see end of Arrangement_on_surface_2/include/CGAL/Arr_geometry_traits/Circle_segment_2.h). Feel free to submit an issue. You can implement it yourself in the meantime and place it next to the exporter.

Comment: @EfiFogel - I think it makes sense to export `X_monotone_curve_2` with type of the curve in the front (line segment or circle arc) - then it'll be easier to write the symmetric importer.